# PayPal directions for PDT don't match Sandbox set up

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

The directions from PayPal for "Activating PDT" include

"Click the Profile subtab."

But in Sandbox, clicking on that link generates an error, a missing cookie.

There seems to be no other way to get to "Website Payment Preferences" to click on the auto return radio button.

I'll continue to poke around, but trying to figure out how to generate an automatic response with PDT to my website.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to setup PDT, please login www.sandbox.paypal.com  , then open https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments directly, you can setup auto return and enable PDT in the page.